# Vryloka Race for 5e v2

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, homebrew, races

So after getting responses and suggestions about the previous version of my vryloka homebrew race, I decided to rework it. So here's version two!

1. **Ability Score Increase.** Your Charisma score increases by 2 and either your Strength or Dexterity score increase by 1.
2. **Size.** Vryloka are about the same size as humans, though they stand taller on average. Your size is Medium.
3. **Speed.** Your walking speed is 30 feet.
4. **Creature Type.** Your creature type is humanoid
5. **Age.** Vryloka have an extended lifespan due to their semi-vampiric nature. They can live up to 500 years old and are immune to any effect that would age them
6. **Ancestral Versatility.** You gain proficiency in one skill and one tool of your choice.
7. **Unliving Nature.** Your creature type is humanoid, yet you register as undead to spells and other effects that detect the presence of the undead creature type. In addition you gain resistance to necrotic damage.
8. **Blood Sap.** Vryloka have the power to feast on the lifeblood of other creatures. When you hit a creature that isn't sn undead or construct with an attack, you can deal an additional 1d4 necrotic damage to that creature. Once per turn when you deal this necrotic damage, you can gain a number of temporary hit points equal to the damage + your proficiency bonus. You can use this feature a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus and regain all uses when you finish a long rest.
9. **Lifeblood.** On your turn, when you score a critical hit with a melee weapon or reduce a creature to 0 hit points with one, you can move up to 10 feet as a reaction. This reactive movement doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity.
10. **Languages.** You can speak, read and write Common and one other language of your choice.

Comment: We require home brewers to wait 72 hours between iterations of homebrew review questions, see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/62294) for more details.

Comment: Not quite. I saw the answers there and reworked the race. I've seen this sort of thing done by others, so I thought it'd be okay, sorry

Comment: Just to cover in case of a misunderstanding: if you're still interested in getting a review you can update this with any relevant details and you should be able to undelete this (otherwise please raise a flag).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the misunderstanding and stuff